# Inserting an array values depends on data table with condition (nested array)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a problem , I'm just a newbie in programming and a bit low on logical problems. I want to generate an array values from a MySQL query result and it has to be nested.

**My Actual Codes that i've been working on:**

```
<?php
    $mostSold_arr = array();
    $subData_array = array();
    $day_arr = array();
    $data = array();
    // Connect to MySQL
    $link = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'db' );
    if ( $link->connect_errno ) {
      die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $link->connect_errno . ") " . $link->connect_error );
    }
    $fetch_data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT products.id as prodID, title, SUM(total_price) as value, orders.order_date as date FROM products  LEFT JOIN order_details  ON order_details.product_id=products.id  LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_details.order_id GROUP BY order_details.product_id ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 2 ") or die(mysqli_error($link));

    while ($row_mainData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_data)) {
        $mostSold_arr['category'] = $row_mainData['title'];
        $mostSold_arr['value'] = $row_mainData['value'];
        $prod_id['prodID'] = $row_mainData['prodID'];
        $mostSold_arr['url'] = "#";
        $mostSold_arr['description'] = "click to drill-down";
        $mostSold_arr['data'] = array();
        $fetch_subData = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT title, SUM(total_price) as value, MONTHNAME(orders.order_date) as date FROM products LEFT JOIN order_details ON order_details.product_id=products.id  LEFT JOIN orders  ON orders.id=order_details.order_id WHERE order_details.product_id=" . $prod_id['prodID'] ." GROUP BY title, date ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 3  ") or die(mysqli_error($link));
        while ($row_subData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_subData)) {
            $subData_arr['category']=$row_subData['date'];
            $subData_arr['value']=$row_subData['value'];
            $day_arr['data'] = array();
            array_push($mostSold_arr['data'],$subData_arr); 

            $fetch_subDataDay = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT title, SUM(total_price) as value, DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, '%M-%d') as date FROM products LEFT JOIN order_details ON  order_details.product_id=products.id LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_details.order_id  WHERE order_details.product_id=" . $row_mainData['prodID'] ." AND DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, '%M-%d') LIKE '%March%' GROUP BY date ORDER BY order_date  LIMIT 3  ") or die(mysqli_error($link));

            while ($row_subDataDay = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_subDataDay)) {
                $subDataDay_arr['category']=$row_subDataDay['date'];
                $subDataDay_arr['value']=$row_subDataDay['value'];
                //array_push($day_arr['data'],$subDataDay_arr);

                if($subData_arr['category'] == 'March'){
                    array_push($mostSold_arr['data'],$subDataDay_arr);
                }
                //array_push($day_arr['data'],$subDataDay_arr);
                //var_dump($subData_arr); 
            }
        } 
      array_push($data, $mostSold_arr); 
    }

    $jsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $fp = fopen('dataColMultiNested.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $jsonData);
    fclose($fp);

    die('<pre>' . print_r($jsonData, 1)); 
    mysqli_close($link); 
    ?>
```

**The Actual Output of the code above:**

```
[
    {
        "category": "ACER E5-473-53C0",
        "value": "2455200.00",
        "url": "#",
        "description": "click to drill-down",
        "data": [
            {
                "category": "March",
                "value": "809100.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-02",
                "value": "27900.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-03",
                "value": "27900.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-04",
                "value": "55800.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "April",
                "value": "781200.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "May",
                "value": "418500.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "ACER ASPIRE E5-551G-F57K LAPTOP",
        "value": "2339220.00",
        "url": "#",
        "description": "click to drill-down",
        "data": [
            {
                "category": "March",
                "value": "449850.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-02",
                "value": "29990.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-03",
                "value": "59980.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "March-07",
                "value": "59980.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "April",
                "value": "689770.00"
            },
            {
                "category": "May",
                "value": "779740.00"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Expected Output(it should be like this)**

```
    [
        {
            "category": "ACER E5-473-53C0",
            "value": "2455200.00",
            "url": "#",
            "description": "click to drill-down",
            "data": [
                {
                    "category": "March",
                    "value": "809100.00",
                    "data": [
                         {
                        "category": "March-02",
                        "value": "27900.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "March-03",
                        "value": "27900.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "March-04",
                        "value": "55800.00"
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "April",
                    "value": "781200.00"
                },
                {
                    "category": "May",
                    "value": "418500.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "category": "ACER ASPIRE E5-551G-F57K LAPTOP",
            "value": "2339220.00",
            "url": "#",
            "description": "click to drill-down",
            "data": [
                {
                    "category": "March",
                    "value": "449850.00",
                    "data": [
                        {
                        "category": "March-02",
                        "value": "29990.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "March-03",
                        "value": "59980.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "category": "March-07",
                        "value": "59980.00"
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "April",
                    "value": "689770.00"
                },
                {
                    "category": "May",
                    "value": "779740.00"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I'm working on this for about 2 nights or more but can find the right solution for my problem.
I hoping that you guys can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally refunded answer, based on the information which lacked in your question and its tags: your desired result is in JSON format (but I must admit that your representation complied with it).

In PHP, you must first create an equivalent array that will look like this:

```
[
    0 => [
        "year" => "2016",
        "data" => [
            0 => [
                "month" => "Dec",
                "data" => [
                    0 => [
                        "day": "Dec 04",
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

It can be built with something not far from your initial code:

```
$fetch_data1 = "Select * From tbl1";
$year = [];

while($row_year = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_data1)){
    $year['year'] = $row_year['year'];

    $fetch_data2 = "Select * From tbl2";
    /* my query needs to loop inside because 
    it will contain condition depends on the retrieved data row   */
    $data = [];
    while($row_month = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_data2)){
        $data['month'] = $row_month['month'];

        $fetch_data3 = "Select * From tbl3";
        /* my query needs to loop inside because
        it will contain condition depends on the retrieved data row   */
        $day = [];
        while($row_day = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_data3)){
            $day['day'] = $row_month['month'] . ' ' . $row_day['day'];
        }
        $data['data'] = $day;
    }
    $year[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: i need it in json format, so the output should have `{ }`. By the way thanks for your reply. I will try it out..

Comment: @Marksmanship Anyway, in PHP you'll get it like I showed. If you want it in JSON format you must actually do `$json_year = json_encode($year);`. And it will result in something using only `{}` and no `[]`.

Comment: with no `[ ]` is it still counted as json format? sorry im just a newbie.

Comment: @Marksmanship `json_encode()` works so that associated arrays (with literal keys) give objects (`{}`) and numeric-key arrays give arrays (`[]`).

Comment: my output seems only returning the last result in query.. why is that?

Comment: @Marksmanship Please precise which is "the last result": at 1st query level? Other? Can you show your input data?

Comment: `last query result from fetch_data`, in "2nd query and 3rd query levels"
In 1st query it seems working fine.

Comment: @Marksmanship So it's what I evoked at the end of my answer: you must adopt another structure, since... Aaah, I get it: it's why you showed a fancy template. Let me some time to change my answer...

Comment: yes. Okay I will wait for your answer. Thanks in advance. If you want to show my codes that I've been working on, just tell me. But i suggest not to, because its very messy. I can cause you headache like i am experiencing right now for about 2 nights until now because of what I want to attain. Anyway, goodluck.

Comment: @Marksmanship See my new answer. It may include bugs. If so, feel free to ask but don't expect a response just now, since I must go to bed: for me now it's past 5 AM!